# optimize query using NOT EXIST

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I want to optimize my query using **NOT EXIST** in following query how can i do so, and please also explain its execution plan

```
 Select I_Ftn, I_Col, count(c.i_id_num) cnt 
From DSCL_ALL.W_CALENDER c 
Where c.UNIT_CODE= '01' 
AND c.i_g_vill = '45'
and c.i_g_code = '1'
and c.survey_year = '2012-2013'
and c.i_number not in (select m.m_indent from w_mill_pur m where m.unit_code = c.unit_code and m.m_vill = c.i_g_vill and m.m_grow = c.i_g_code)  
Group By I_Ftn, I_Col
ORDER BY I_ftn, I_col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to try this :

```
Select I_Ftn, I_Col, count(c.i_id_num) cnt 
From DSCL_ALL.W_CALENDER c 
Where c.UNIT_CODE= '01' 
AND c.i_g_vill = '45'
and c.i_g_code = '1'
and c.survey_year = '2012-2013'
and not exists (select 1 from w_mill_pur m where m.unit_code = c.unit_code and m.m_vill = c.i_g_vill and m.m_grow = c.i_g_code and m.m_indent = c.i_number)  
Group By I_Ftn, I_Col
ORDER BY I_ftn, I_col)
```

It's more efficient because of the added where clause : Oracle is able to run a more filtered subquery and then just test if the result set is empty or not.
You may also want to check that you have a (unit_code, m_vill, m_grow, m.m_indent) index for w_mill_pur.

The "not in" way require one more join in the main query (the subquery result set with the main one).

Regards,

Comment: Oracle is quite smart when optmizing `NOT IN` conditions. I wouldn't be surprised if your statement would result in the same execution plan as the original one.

Comment: I suppose it depends of the availables indexes, but yeah, Oracle optimizer is pretty good at this.
Meanwhile, having a better original query still remains a better start point :)

Comment: wooh my previous query's execution time was 14.53 now it is taking only 1 sec. thank you FabienM.

Comment: just 1 more thing I wanna ask in subquery why we are using ((select 1 from w_mill_pur m where m.unit .....)

Comment: You can select "1", "2", "*", or any columns tuple you have in w_mill_pur. Oracle will just check the emptiness of the resultset, whatever content it can have.

Comment: I observed that null is little bit faster then "1", "2" (a microsecond difference is there)

Answer (score 0):

There is difference between "NOT IN" and "NOT EXISTS". Please follow the link by ASKTOM -

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:442029737684